# Multiple $watchCollection for unknown number of arrays?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am battling to find a way to save data from two (for now) sortable lists to a database.

```
  $scope.dropTarget = null;
  $scope.$watchCollection('lists[0].items', function() {
      console.log('watch 0');
      $scope.dropTarget = $scope.lists[0];
  });
  $scope.$watchCollection('lists[1].items', function() {
      console.log('watch 1');
  $scope.dropTarget = $scope.lists[1];
  });
```

This code I am experimenting with from another thread [Handling moving of item across lists in angular-ui sortable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182297/handling-moving-of-item-across-lists-in-angular-ui-sortable)

However, the number of lists I have will be variable depending on how they are created by the user. Is there any way to use $watchCollection on an unknown quantity of items?

Is there perhaps a better way to save angular-ui sortable data to a mongo backend? So that items moved to other categories are saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use a  equality watch:

```
$scope.$watch('lists', function(newVal, oldVal){
console.log('changed');
}, true);
```

this will trigger whenever something is changed in the lists, even if it is for instance: lists[0].item.property

Comment: Thanks, but will this help me find the target container? For eg. this is the codepen from the angularui docs http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/uFile what I am looking for is a way to get the ID of the second list once an item has been drag dropped. so - itemA has been moved from categoryA to categoryB, all of these eventually being mongo _ids so that the moving can be updated in the db.

Comment: But on save, why dont you just save the two lists agian?
For me it sounds like you want to have some kind of "dirty" on the list, and then only update those, if i get you right ?

Comment: This would work if I only had 2 lists, but what if I had 5? Then 3 lists would not be changed, and it would be a waste to resend the whole lot to the server. So yes, kind of a ng-dirty for the changed list. The example in original question works well but only if you know the number of lists.